# Alphabetical scroll or Android Fast Scroll in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy itself (and kivy-garden) doesn't seem to have any implementation of Alphabetical Scroll or android's Fast Scroll.

For the purpose of this question, I'm referring the the ability to quickly jump to a certain part in a list (normally by a small swipe rather than by repeatedly swiping down pages and pages of the list), mostly indexed by alphabet. Most commonly seen in contact list browsers.

First question - have I missed any implementations of the above or similar?

Second question - is anyone working on something similar?

Comment: Kivy is just a GUI. It has no lists. Python has lists.
Do you mean a Spinner instead? If yes, you have to sort() the values of the Spinners in order to be in alphabetical order. Similarly, you have to create the quick jump for your software.

Comment: Kivy certainly has Lists (a widget type, not a data type). The current implementation is ListView, and RecycleView is the preferred experimental one.